How to Include CustomJson Converters while generating api clients using Nswag?
I have following DTO class in api project which uses RangeConverter.
 public class DTO
  {      
      public string Name { get; set; }
     
      [JsonConverter(typeof(RangeConverter))]
      public VersionRange Version { get; set; }
  }

The RangeConverter is in different project and have different namespace which is referenced in api project.
When the client is generated using nswag i only see following code without RangeConverter. decoration.
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.4.5.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
  public partial class DTO
  {
      /// <summary>Name.</summary>
      [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Name", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
      public string Name { get; set; }
  
      [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Version", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
      public VersionRange Version { get; set; }
  
  
  }


I have even tried setting up JsonConveter property in nswag.json to include RangeConverter. It includes it for namesake showing the error for namespace not found.

**Is there any way to consider RangeConverter while generating api client and decorate VersionRange with RangeConverter ?
